# How can I set different button colors?

Tags: html, css

For my final project for my HTML class, I changed all my links into buttons. I got the colors to change when your hover over and click the buttons, but I can't figure out how to set the colors for visited buttons, and not visited buttons. I thought I could just change all my CSS code, but my buttons won't show if its link was visited or not. Below is my code.

```css
      body {
        background-image: url('https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/933807761352302039/DE60758ED5AED9417FE28BEE0B29DEFA543FC500/');/*Image source*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;/*If changed to "repeat", image will repeat*/
        background-attachment: fixed;/*Does your image stay in one spot, or does it move as you scroll?*/
        background-size: cover;/*The resolution of the image*/
      }
h1 {
 font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
 font-size: 38px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Changa', sans-serif;
 font-size: 34px; 
}

p {
  font-family: 'DotGothic16', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

button {
 font-family: 'Megrim', cursive; 
}

  /* unvisited link */
  button:link  {
    color: black;
    }

  /* visited link */
  button:visited {
    color: #3399ff;
    }

  /* mouse over link */
  button:hover {
    color: #ff3333;
    }

  /* selected link */
  button:active  {
    color: powderblue;
    }
  button:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

  button:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

  button:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-style: wavy;
    }

  button:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-style: wavy;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Team 5FX~Homepage</title>
    <!-- The style.css file allows you to change the look of your web pages.
         If you include the next line in all your web pages, they will all share the same look.
         This makes it easier to make new pages for your site. -->
    <link href="/homepage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
   <!--Tab icon. "shortcut icon" tells the webpage to make the image the shortcut icon. Next is the image file type. Next is the image file name.-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="Team_5FX.png">
        <!--Background image for website  -->
       
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Changa:wght@200&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DotGothic16&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Megrim&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body style= "color: white; ">
  
    <h1>Welcome to the homepage of Team 5FX's website!</h1>
    
    <h2>Navigate between the different links below.</h2>
    
    <fieldset>
    <legend style="font-family: 'DotGothic16', sans-serif; font-size: 16;">Click the link if you are one of the new members of Team 5FX.</legend> <a style="" href="https://staff-assignment.noahjospeh.repl.co/"><button style= "background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); height:90px; width:180px; cursor:pointer; font-size:22px;" title="Team 5FX Introduction"><strong>Team 5FX Introduction</strong></button></a>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset><legend style="font-family: 'DotGothic16', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">Click the to get to our online menu.</legend> <a style="font-family: 'Megrim', cursive;" href="https://noah-joseph.neocities.org/Food.html"><button style= "background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); height:90px; width:180px; cursor:pointer; font-size:36px;" title="Meal Menu"><strong>Meal Menu</strong></button></a></fieldset>
    
    <fieldset><legend style="font-family: 'DotGothic16', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">Click the link to get to take our math test.</legend><a style="font-family: 'Megrim', cursive;" href="https://noah-joseph.neocities.org/Math_Test_Form.html"><button style= "background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); height:90px; width:180px; cursor:pointer; font-size:26px;" title="Math Test Form"><strong>Math Test Form</strong></button></a></fieldset>
    
    <fieldset><legend style="font-family: 'DotGothic16', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">Click the link to read our news article.</legend><a style="font-family: 'Megrim', cursive;" href="https://noah-joseph.neocities.org/News_Article.html"><button style= "background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); height:90px; width:180px; cursor:pointer; font-size:36px;" title="News Article"><strong>News Article</strong></button></a></fieldset>
    
    <fieldset><legend style="font-family: 'DotGothic16', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">Click the link to read a short story.</legend><a style="" href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JTbaGVPuXelPEWNR7WnARyJWwWmT64oSpWyUzldvjRM/edit?usp=sharing"><button style= "background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); height:90px; width:180px; cursor:pointer; font-size:28px;" title="There Are Two of Me"><strong>There Are Two of Me</strong></button></a></fieldset>
    
    <fieldset><legend style="font-family: 'DotGothic16', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">Click the link to learn just how dangerous your favorite FNAF&trade; characters are, and what name to call them when you fall out of your chair from their jumpscares. (You can hover over them!)</legend><a style="font-family: 'Megrim', cursive;" href="https://noah-joseph.neocities.org/My-Table.html"><button style= "background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); height:90px; width:180px; cursor:pointer; font-size:20px;" title="Comparing Animatronics From FNAF&trade;"><strong>Comparing Animatronics From FNAF&trade;</strong></button></a></fieldset>
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cookieconsent.popupsmart.com/src/js/popper.js"></script><script> window.start.init({Palette:"palette6",Mode:"floating left",Theme:"classic",ButtonText:"I like cookies!",Location:"https://noah-joseph.neocities.org/cookies.html",Time:"5",})</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using buttons, just apply the style to the links themselves. From a CSS standpoint, you can make a link look just like a button.

Comment: @imvain2 Since I was able to get the text color and text decoration to change, wouldn't there be a way to get the visited and not visited text colors to also change?

Comment: visited applies to links - see e.g. [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Comment: As @imvain2 said, you should really change your links back to `<a>` tags. It's semantically correct and you can easily style them to look like buttons.